# pass a json string as an argument to Python script causes quotes problems

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I want to write a script that takes in a single argument, a string that contains some json data, and (for sake of simplicity) prints something.

```
import argparse
import json

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='json load and print')
parser.add_argument('-i','--inputstring', help='Input String in JSON format',required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

inp = parser.parse_args()

data = json.loads(inp)

print(data['Employees'])
```

When I run this from command line I get an error because of the double quotes that I use to wrap the string ending up matching double quotes in the json:

```
python myscript.py -i "{ "Employees": "name name"}"
Unrecognized arguments Employees...
```

If I switch the json double quotes to single quotes, the json parser will not work.

How do I handle something like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code will work as expected if you change how you assign your input variable. Change this line:

```
inp = parser.parse_args()
```

to

```
inp = args.inputstring
```

`parse_args()` returns an `argparse.Namespace` object, so you need to retrieve the input from that object prior to passing it to the parser.  In addition, you will need to escape the double quotes in your shell command.  I get the expected output with the above change run with:

```
python myscript.py -i "{ \"Employees\": \"name name\"}"
```

Answer (score 4):

You should escape the internal double quotes in the JSON:

```
python myscript.py -i "{ \"Employees\": \"name name\"}"
```

But looking at your code, there are a couple of other reasons it may not be working:

1. you're assigning `args` and `inp` the same value, return value of the function call: `parser.parse_args()`. Perhaps you meant to assign `inp = args.inputstring`
2. you've tagged the question as python2 but looking at your `print(...)` statement, it looks like you've written for python3

Answer (score 0):

You should replace double quotes with single quotes:

```
python myscript.py -i "{ 'Employees': 'name name'}"
```

Comment: The JSON still can't be parsed without an extra step to replace the single quotes with double quotes after the argument is parsed.